# Big sur QT is not showing widgets

Tags: python, pyside2, macos-big-sur

Since today's release of Big Sur, my QT application stopped working, no any errors, project runs, just Windows are not shown.

using Python with a Pyside2, writing, and launching with a Pycharms.
Was fully functional yesterday - before upgrade.
Tested even with a simplest empty window:

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = QWidget()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Same nothing shown.

Can anyone suggest what can I check? Where to begin?

Comment: just to clarify: Python 3.9

Answer (score 5):

after long long research - very weird solution... but until will be fixed by Qt - please see here :
[Apps not popping up on macOS Big Sur 11.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64833558/apps-not-popping-up-on-macos-big-sur-11-0-1#_=)_
for me it was a life saver- hope it will help someone

Comment: Thanks for this, I had the same issue with frustrating hours of debugging not realizing it was the upgrade to Big Sur grrr

Comment: update!!!! using this approach actually makes breakpoints to crash the Python!!!

Comment: after another research - this only the thing that really helps :https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/pyqt5-and-big-sur.2260773/